# Linq Contains() Not supported

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity

```
(from a in GetCtx().Application
                     where identifiers.Contains(a.os + ":" + a.osIdentifier)
                     select a.id).ToList();
```

It is giving me NotSupportedException:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   Format(System.String, System.Object, System.Object)' method, and this
>   method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Can anyone tell me How I can solve this?

Comment: what are `identifiers`?

Comment: its a string. I formatted it in a way to have those two parameters e.g "3:com.app.android"

Comment: Are you using EF4 or a newer version?

Comment: Are you sure this is the right code / error message?  The error is complaining about String.Format, not Contains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use LINQ to Entities against SQL Server you can use [SqlFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.aspx):

```
(from a in GetCtx().Application
 where identifiers.Contains(SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)a.os) + ":" + a.osIdentifier)
 select a.id).ToList();
```